# OS X login page like HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, macos, authentication

I know the Title is a little obscure, but I will try to explain my best. Since OS X Lion the login screen of the Macs presents a row of images of the available users. Once you click one of those images, the rest disappear, centering the clicked one and revealing a password field.

I want to do a similar thing in a web-app. I have a few users, and I want them to click on their image to reveal the password field.

I searched for similar options, but can't find anything, and I don't even know how to proceed. I guess JQuery or Javascript would be necessary, but those I know little to nothing (HTML & CSS shouldn't be a problem, but well, I don't even know how to start this simple thing... )

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend... no matter how much the NSA are watching. Use it to search for tutorials, these are the best way to learn. Mostly CSS will be needed to make it look like the OSX login screen... maybe a bit of jQuery.

Within in seconds I found [this page](http://www.ajaxshake.com/en/JS/12541/login.html) of many examples of login forms. And then I found [this one](http://www.ajaxshake.com/demo/EN/745/0381f3e2/mac-login-form-with-jquery-loginformmac.html) that looks very similar to an OSX login page.